# When is data big enough to use Hadoop?

Tags: database, hadoop, bigdata

My employer runs a Hadoop cluster, and as our data is rarely larger than 1GB, I have found that Hadoop is rarely needed to meet the needs of our office (this isn't big data), but my employer seems to want to be able to say we're using our Hadoop cluster, so we're actively seeking out data that needs analysis using our big fancy tool.

I've seen some reports saying that anything less than 5tb shouldn't utilize hadoop. What's the magic size where Hadoop becomes a practical solution to data analysis?

Comment: As a simple rule of thumb, if you can fit your data in a database hosted on a single machine you don't have big data and you do not need Hadoop. 1GB is not big data. 5TB is getting close but can still probably be handled on a single machine. Hadoop is for when you have so much data that in order to process it you need to break it down into chunks and process it on multiple machines. If you can fit it in on single DB it is always better to do so.

Comment: Hadoop is not a DB replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't something like magic size. Hadoop is not only about the amount of data, it include resources and processing "cost". It's not the same process one image that could require a lot of memory and CPU than parse a text file. And haoop is being used for both.

To justify the use of hadoop you need to answer the follow questions:

- Is your process able to run in one machine and complete the work on time ?
- How fast is your data growing?

It's not the same read one time by day 5TB to generate a report than to read 1GB ten times by second from a customer facing API. But if you haven't facing these kind of problems before, very probably that you don't require use hadoop to process your 1GB :)